# Angular 5 routing support for IE9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular5

In IE9, routing is going in infinite loop in url ? In docs its written it does support IE9. I have enabled all the polyfills required for IE9 in polyfills.ts, still its not working. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the interesting code snippets that bother you.

Comment: @DiabolicWords , Its just one simple project with basic routing and its working fine across all browsers but breaking down in only IE9. So there is no code snippet which is bothering me, its about the compatibility issue.